# Uploading file to ASP.NET generic handler keeps resulting in request timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a video file using a generic handler, but the request either times out or buffers with no error thrown every time. I've debugged enough to know that other form data is passed just fine, but when commenting back in the code to upload the video, it's back to square one.

I know video files can be quite large, but the one I'm trying to upload is a .mov file only 15 seconds long. Because of these large files, I'm trying to upload the videos to an Azure blob storage account. My initial idea was to store the files on the web server, but that also results in request timeouts (and in case of a server restart, all files from the upload directory would perish). So, I've boiled it down to something within the .ashx file, or generic handler, that I'm using.

I can't seem to find any other reported issues on slow uploading for generic handlers. The specific error I get for the timeout is:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

That error occurs at the line where I am attempting to upload the file to Azure Blob Storage:

```
blobClient.Upload(stream);
```

**Markup**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="uploadVideoFile" type="file" accept="video/*">
</form>
```

**AJAX call**

```
const file = document.getElementById("uploadVideoFile").files[0];
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", file);

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/FileUploadHandler.ashx",
    data: fd,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
        console.log("Video file was uploaded successfully.");
    }
});
```

**FileUploadHandler.ashx.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace WebApplication1
{
   
    public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
                AzureBlob az = new AzureBlob();
                az.Upload(postedFile);
            }
        }

        public class AzureBlob
        {
            private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobService;
            BlobContainerClient _blobContainer;

            public AzureBlob()
            {
                 _blobService = new BlobServiceClient("MY_CONNECTION_STRING");
            }

            public void Upload(HttpPostedFile file)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    _blobContainer = _blobService.GetBlobContainerClient("my-container-name");
                    _blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
                    _blobContainer.SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
                    BlobClient blobClient = _blobContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);
                    Stream stream = file.InputStream;
                    blobClient.Upload(stream);
                    var fileUrl = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem finally solved. I had to edit the execution timeout on my Web.config to be longer. By default, a request times out in 110 seconds.

Now, given that these requests were running well beyond 110 seconds, I thought they would time out when hitting that interval. But I was wrong in this approach of thinking, as the *server-side* code would expire in that time, not the *client-side* code. You see, the AJAX request took a while to upload the video file, but it still had called the generic handler at its initial calling, therefore starting the C# code. So, if the file had been finally uploaded in a time span longer than 110 seconds, the server-side response would have already timed out.

Here is the formatting in the Web.config file; I'll also include the increased request length limit, as I needed that to pass large file chunks as well.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="600" />
</system.web>
```